# how would I run Selenium test through the GRID using C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

i have just set-up the selenium grid on my local machine and everything seems to be up and running.

my question is, is there a way I can run the test case from selenium grid node (command prompt)?

I am using WebDriver for creating my testcase using .Net

Comment: What do you mean by "is there a way I can run the test case from selenium grid node (command prompt)?"

Comment: so let me ask you, can we run any test case from selenium grid? the reason i asked is i saw the youtube video where they he runs the test case through selenium grid using python.

Comment: U can run any SELENIUM test through the grid. That test can be written in Java Ruby Python (C# as well, I think). But what is your question?

Comment: my question is how would I run selenium test through the grid using C# :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

// Requires reference to WebDriver.Support.dll
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

class GoogleSuggest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver.

        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.

        // Further note that other drivers (InternetExplorerDriver,
        // ChromeDriver, etc.) will require further configuration 
        // before this example will work. See the wiki pages for the
        // individual drivers at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki
        // for further information.
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
        DesiredCapabilities.FirefoxDriver());


        //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
        //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        query.SendKeys("Cheese");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        query.Submit();

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("cheese"); });

        // Should see: "Cheese - Google Search"
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);

        //Close the browser
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.... interesting i was thinking that i could be able to run the test cases through command propmt

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
        DesiredCapabilities.FirefoxDriver());

OR in c#

IWebDriver driver;    
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();      
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
new Uri("http://hub-cloud.com/wd/hub/"), capability);    
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```